# How to find characteristic polynomial of $B$ in terms of $A$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, block-matrices

> $$B := \begin{pmatrix} A+nI && -E\\ -E^T&& nI\end{pmatrix}$$ where $E$ is the all-ones matrix. If the eigenvalues of $n \times n$ matrix $A$ are known, is it possible to find the eigenvalues of $B$?

I find the characteristic polynomial of $B$ to be

$$\begin{pmatrix} xI-(A+nI) && -E\\ -E^T&& (x-n)I\end{pmatrix}$$

I found that

$$\det(xI-B)= \det(x-n)I\times \{(xI-(A+nI)-E(x-n)^{-1}E^T\}$$

but cant find the characteristic polynomial of $B$ in terms of $A$. Can I get some help here?

Comment: no, the eigenvalues of $B$ are not determined by the eigenvalues of $A$ alone -- for example when $n = 2$ you can check that $B$ has different eigenvalues with $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. E.g. $A$ has a zero spectrum when it is the zero matrix or the nilpotent Jordan block $J_2(0)$, but the characteristic polynomials of $\pmatrix{0&-E\\ -E&0}$ and $\pmatrix{J_2(0)&-E\\ -E&0}$ are $x^4-4x^2$ and $x^4-4x^2-2x$ respectively.

In general, if $A$ is $m\times m$ and its characteristic polynomial is $f$, then
\begin{aligned}
\det\left((y+n)I-B\right)
&=\det\pmatrix{yI-A&-E\\ -E&yI}\\
&=\det\left((yI-A)(yI)-E^2\right)\\
&=\det\left(y(yI-A)-mee^T\right)\\
&=\det\left(y(yI-A)\right)-me^T\operatorname{adj}\left(y(yI-A)\right)e\\
&=y^mf(y)-my^{m-1}e^T\operatorname{adj}(yI-A)e,
\end{aligned}
where $e$ denotes the all-one vector. It follows that
$$
\det(xI-B)=(x-n)^mf(x-n)-m(x-n)^{m-1}e^T\operatorname{adj}\left((x-n)I-A\right)e.
$$
If $A$ happens to be a diagonal matrix, the expression $e^T\operatorname{adj}\left((x-n)I-A\right)e$ above can be rewritten as $(x-n)^mf(x-n)-m(x-n)^{m-1}f'(x-n)$, but in general, it is not solely determined by the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much+1